# How to extract the single type of a parameterized type using jdt

Tags: java, list, parsing, eclipse-jdt

I am trying to parse some java source files and get some info using AST.  Currently I want to somehow get the type of parameterized types eg from `List<String>` I need the `String`.

```
public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment f) {
if (f.getParent() instanceof FieldDeclaration) {
    FieldDeclaration d = (FieldDeclaration) f.getParent();
    if (d.getType().isParameterizedType()) {
        System.out.println("Par type : " + d.getType().toString());
    }
}
}
```

This snippet gives me the `List<String>`.
Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Nothing runs. I just parse source code files. Since I get the `List<String>` or the `ArrayList<double>` there is no way to get rid of the `List/ArrayList` part and get `String/double`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the `Type` to `ParametrizedType` and extract the inner type.

```
public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment f) {
  if (f.getParent() instanceof FieldDeclaration) {
    FieldDeclaration d = (FieldDeclaration) f.getParent();
    if (d.getType().isParameterizedType()) {
      ParameterizedType parType = (ParameterizedType) d.getType();
      System.out.println("Par type : " + parType.typeArguments().get(0).toString());
    }
  }
}
```